# When is a prime $p$ a quadratic residue modulo $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Simple. When $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, it is a quadratic residue, and when $p \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ it is not a residue.

So can we have a nice expression for the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$?
Something of the type
$$\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=(-1)^{f(p)}$$
where $f(p)$ is a function of $p$ (say a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ or a rational function) which is an even integer when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and an odd integer when $p \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.

Essentially, we want a simple (polynomial, rational function,...) function from $\mathbb{Z}-3\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
Now the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^*$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with an isomorphism given by
$$\Phi:(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^* \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\Phi(x)=\log_{2}x$$
Can this map be used to construct a map from $\mathbb{Z}-3\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ that we are looking for? So that elements of the form $3k+1$ are mapped to $0$ and elements of the form $3k-1$ are mapped to $1$?

At least for $3$ we have such an isomorphism to work with. If we take $5$, then we don't even have that luxury.Is there an expression of this type for $\left(\frac{p}{5}\right)$? I know that reciprocity might help in the general case, but I am interested in these simple cases first.

Comment: Could you add some more clarity on the nature of the mapping?  It seems to me that $\Phi$ is exactly the mapping you want already.  For any (odd) prime modulus $q$ there is an isomorphism between $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^*$ and $\mathbb Z/(q-1) \mathbb Z$ which determines $(\frac{p}{q})$ by simple parity.  This is essentially Euler's criterion.  I don't understand why you say $5$ doesn't have that luxury.

Comment: @ErickWong: All I want is an expression of the form $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)=(-1)^{f(p)}$ for some "simple" function $f$. The mapping I showed is just part of my attempt at constructing such an $f$.

Comment: Is discrete log considered "simple"?  That's what you seem to be using for the case $3$.

Comment: Even if we allow for that, how do we meaningfully obtain a map $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}-3\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ so that $f(3k+1)$ is even and $f(3k-1)$ is odd?

Comment: what's wrong with the identity map?  That's why I don't think you have the question clear in your mind.

Comment: If we use the identity map, then $f(p)$ is odd for every prime $p$. We want to somehow separate $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ from $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ using an indicator function. And I am asking if such an indicator can have a simple form.

Comment: For instance, the indicator $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ distinguishes $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$ (in which case $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ is even) from $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$ (in which case $\frac{p^2-1}{8}$ is odd). I was hoping to capture such an indicator for modulo $3$.

Comment: By "identity map" I mean composing it with $\Phi$: remember, my previous comment said that $\Phi$ is already the mapping you wanted.  The isomorphism already gives you $0$ when $p$ is $1\pmod 3$ and $1$ when $p$ is $2\pmod 3$.  Where's the problem?